# Is it possible to draw multicolored edges between nodes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

For my application, each edge has one or more meaning to the user.
Therefore, I would like to give the same edge multiple colors.

Can it do this?

Here is a workaround, that illustrates what I want to do: a blue/red edge:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edge('a', 'b')

pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, edge_color='darkblue', alpha=0.4)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, edge_color='indianred', style='dashed', alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So your work around is working well I suppose, what other feature you are asking about ?

Comment: @AbdallahSobehy A single edge have more than one meaning to the user visually.

Comment: Yes, I get your point. I want to make sure I understand what is the drawback of your solution or in other words what is it that you want to improve ? Because for me it is working you can seen that this edge has 2 colors

Comment: @AbdallahSobehy However, there are situations where I need more colors, such as seven. I do not know how many colors will need at most, because the application is still being developed. Perhaps, six or seven colors. Also, the code that I used is very ugly

Comment: I understand but don't you think it is too much to have 7 colors in one edge for example I believe if they are more than 3 you will not be able to tell.

Comment: @AbdallahSobehy Talking with a work colleague, he said it would be very polluted visually various colors have an edge, so I decided that I will draw several graphs, and not just one. In fact, it would be illegible an edge with various colors. Thanks for listening.